# How to get response from external js which is not in npm (node modules)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to get response from external js which is not in npm (node modules).

Here i need to call some functions from react file and expecting the return value from external js file to be utilized in my component

Comment: Use a class? It's hard to see what you're asking with no code.

Answer (score 0):

Appending an external script on `componentDidMount()` is an option.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "path/to/your/file.js";
  script.async = true;
  script.onload = () => this.externalScriptLoaded();
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Then inside `externalScriptLoaded`, you can access functions in your external script using `window` object.

```
externalScriptLoaded() {
  window.externaljs.someFunction(); // replace externaljs
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to make sure that the external module is loaded before you call any function from that module. It is okay to do unless the external js manipulates the DOM.

Edit: you can load the external js using `<script>` tag